# Declaring XML output parameters with ADODB in ASP Classic

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, adodb

I'm working with an ASP Classic legacy code base attempting to call an existing SQL Server stored procedure that declares output parameters with an XML data type.

However, every time I try to execute the stored proc I get this error:

```
0x80040e14 - Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type xml to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

I've experimented with a list of ADODB types, trying to find one that works, and haven't had any luck.  I've also grepped our legacy code base for examples of other stored procs with xml output parameters being called, but wasn't able to find any.

Is there a way around this without updating the stored procedure to not use an XML type for its output parameter?  For example, could it be possible to declare a null output parameter type or just ignore this parameter?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: can you post line of code throwing this error

Comment: @David If you still having this issue, this might interest you. [Answer to XML output parameters with ADODB in ASP Classic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23869217/692942).