# XML output parameters with ADODB in ASP Classic

Tags: sql, xml, asp-classic, adodb

I found this error looking for a solution to a problem of retrieving XML at ASP classic:
[Declaring XML output parameters with ADODB in ASP Classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099334/declaring-xml-output-parameters-with-adodb-in-asp-classic)

I have the same error working with Classic ASP and SQL Server 2003. I used to work with a .dll in VB6, where I could get the XML code. But now I need to do it from SQL direct to ASP.
Did you manage to solve it?

My code in classic ASP so far is:

```vb
set objCommandoOP = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCommandoOP.ActiveConnection = objConexion
objCommandoOP.CommandType = adcmdStoredProc
objCommandoOP.CommandText="spProducesXML"
set ParamEnt = objCommandoOP.CreateParameter("@CodOne", adInteger, adParamInput, 4, Entidad())
objCommandoOP.Parameters.Append ParamEnt
set ParamUser = objCommandoOP.CreateParameter("@CodTwo", adInteger, adParamInput, 4, Usuario())
objCommandoOP.Parameters.Append ParamUser
set ParamFrac = objCommandoOP.CreateParameter("@GroupType", adInteger, adParamInput, 4, Request("GrupoFrac"))
objCommandoOP.Parameters.Append ParamFrac
set ParamReturn = objCommandoOP.CreateParameter("@paramReturn", adXML, adParamInputOutput, 4, 0)

objCommandoOP.Parameters.Append ParamReturn

set objResultseto = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
'Internal procedure that execute the ddbb sp
ExecProcedure objResultseto, adOpenStatic, objCommandoOP

sResult = "<dmo:OperationImport xmlns:dmo='http://www.example.es/XML' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' />"
sResult = sResult & ParamReturn
sResultXML= sResultXML & "</dmo:OperationImport>"
```

The error happens at the "adXML" line, since as David I cannot find a XML variable to bring the parameter from the ddbb. I try to take it as paramReturn of the SQL procedure (with FOR XML EXPLICIT), any other ideas?

Comment: +1 For at least posting some code, unlike *[David](http://stackoverflow.com/users/63229/david)*.

Comment: What does your stored procedure look like?

Comment: Code formatting cannot use **bold** markdown so you end up with `**bold**` around your `adXML` that's why I [added the comment line](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23867480/2) below to point to your `adXML` variable. But you've removed it so each to their own I guess.

Comment: I just removed it since you told me it, haven't notice it before, sorry!

Comment: @MikaelEriksson my SQL procedure is just a query with a RETURNS that is XML, coming from an FOR XML EXPLICIT. I have executed the query to be sure is sending back the XML correct code, and it does. So I thought it might be in the ASP code.

Comment: @JavierSalazar You can't return XML like that you have to stream it using the `ADODB.Stream` object.

Comment: @Lankymart thanks! Trying what you suggested below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could make with a workaround. basically sending the parameter from SQL as a `varchar(max)` and not as XML, then treating it in ASP as a Object Resulset were I convert the varchar to an XML. Tried up with files of more than 30k characters and still works. 
Classic ASP code so far:

`

```
dim objResultseto
set objResultseto = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
AbrirProcAlmacenado objResultseto, adOpenStatic, objCommand             

if objResultseto.EOF= false then        
 while (objResultseto.EOF = false)

        Set xmlOperaciones = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")
            xmlOperaciones.Async = False
            xmlOperaciones.loadXML(objResultseto("XML_VAR"))
            xmlOperaciones.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces","xmlns:dmo='http://www.webpage.com/'"
            if xmlOperaciones.parseError = 0 then 
                xmlOperaciones.Save("C:\Example.xml")
                sResultado= "OK"
            end if
            objResultseto.movenext
 wend
else
 response.Write("There are no these kind of operations")
 response.end
end if
```

´

Remember that this is just a workaround.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The reason you receive an error on the `adXML` line is because there is no `DataTypeEnum` for this data type.

In [ADO 2.6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the `ADODB.Command` object was extended to support passing and receiving XML data using the `ADODB.Stream` object.

To pass an XML data type in the `ADODB.Command` use the `CommandStream` property

```vb
Set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Call stream.Open()
Call stream.WriteText(xml, adWriteChar)

'Set ADODB.Stream to CommandStream before executing ADODB.Command
command.CommandStream = stream
command.Execute(, , adExecuteStream)
```

To retrieve an XML data type use the dynamic property `Output Stream`

```vb
Set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Call stream.Open()

'Set ADODB.Stream to dynamic property "Output Stream"
command.Properties("Output Stream") = stream
command.Execute(, , adExecuteStream)
'Reset stream position before reading
stream.Position = 0
xml = stream.ReadText
```

---

**Useful links**

- [Capturing XML output from ADO using a Stream object](http://alleged.org.uk/pdc/2003/10/08.html)

Comment: this solution does not work, should I do something like `command.Properties("Output Stream") = Response`? It fails directly on compiling the code :/

Comment: @JavierSalazar These are only examples I'm not going to re-write your code for you. `command` is the generic name for *my* `ADODB.Command` object in the example just typing that in your code won't work as your `ADODB.Command` is called `objCommandoOP` for starters.

Comment: I have tried before the streaming style, but always came with an error at the time of calling: `command.Properties("Output Stream") = stream`. Its the 800a0cc1 from ADODB.Command: _Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal_

Comment: @JavierSalazar `objCommandoOP.Properties("Output Stream")` property will give you access to your `FOR XML` output, but you will need to assign it to an *open* `ADODB.Stream`. Once you have the stream you can read / write it or use `Response.BinaryWrite()` to output direct to the Response buffer.

Comment: @JavierSalazar If you get that error there are few possibilities `1.` Your not outputing your XML correctly in your stored procedure using `FOR XML`. `2.` You are not using `ADO 2.6` as it wasn't until that version that streaming was supported from the `ADODB.Command` object.

Comment: `1` How can I check it? I have executed the query and gives me a valid XML line to click on it and see at sql server management studio. I'm using an easy query with FOR XML EXPLICIT. `2` I've checked it, and my version is 6.0.

Comment: @JavierSalazar `2.` [How to check for MDAC version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301202).

Comment: I was meaning about how to check if my sp Procedure is generating a good XML file. Anyway I run what you told me and I've MDAC 2.8 (SP2 ON WINDOWS SERVER 2003 SP2).

Comment: @JavierSalazar From what I can tell, not had this issue myself but if your getting that error try changing your connection string to `PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB` if it isn't already. Also looking on google mention this error due to a mismatch in encoding, for example SQL Server returning `UTF-8` encoded data when it's expecting something else.

Comment: got a workaround solution, cannot post today cuz of I've not enough reputation. Thanks anyway for all the help.